# What is "spore:outlink_count" in Google Search Console's product structured data section?

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data

I have notice something on my site structured data:

> ```
> spore:outlink_count:13
> ```

I don't have idea about this but I came across it today.
Does anyone know about this one? If someone know about this please tell us some details about it.

Answer (score 1):

I did a Google search and the top result led me to:

> That is pretty much meaningless and probably shouldn't be cluttering up the display. I'll pass this along to the relevant Google team

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/GQv5qfbPLt4/klA_CxLAEwAJ